# Updating an iphone app with plist

Tags: xcode, plist

I am a question about plist. If i have already released an app say version 1.0, which contain a plist, allows user to save their data in. If i now release a version 2.0, will the plist data entered by the user in the previous version being deleted.

I have tried on my phone, by using build and run from the xcode seems it doesn;t delete the pervious. But i am not sure will it be the same in itunes store.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're saying that user's save their data in the plist, I will assume you are saving that plist to the documents directory. If that is the case, I don't see why it will be an issue as the directory is persistent between app updates. And if you are providing a new plist file with this update then it won't overwrite that plist file unless you instruct it to as the new plist file will be inside the bundle. You might want to check whether a plist exists already in the documents directory. If it exists, perform some kind of merge operation between both the plist files.

Comment: Need some help man. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389375/xcode-camera-integration-tutorials