# iPhone Xcode Camera Integration Tutorials

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera

I need some help. I need to integrate the camera into my app, and I want to learn about the following:

1. I need the camera button on my view so that clicking it opens the camera view.
2. I take a picture
3. I need to code so that I have access to the Phone Gallery and then
      display a pic in another view.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176020/how-to-take-picture-from-camera-using-iphone-app

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) is the tool you need. It will do most of the stuff in that checklist.

For the button you can create a custom button with graphics or if you are planning to use a tool bar or a navigation bar to hold your buttons, you can create the bar button using the [`UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera) system item. This will give you the framework image.

On tapping it, you will create a `UIImagePickerController` instance and present it modally.

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

As you must've noticed that it has a `delegate` property which is defined as `id < UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> delegate;` so you will have to adopt both the protocols but in most cases you implement only two methods – `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:` and `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`. There is another method in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol but that's deprecated. Don't use it even if you see it mentioned a lot around here. You would expect the cancel handler to be written like this,

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The other methods is where you do most of the stuff.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    // You have the image. You can use this to present the image in the next view like you require in `#3`.

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Taking the picture is done automatically by the `UIImagePickerController` instance. However if you want to override their controls, you can do so by setting `showsCameraControls` to `NO` and then implementing your own `cameraOverlayView`. If you've done so and have assigned a button to take the picture, you can actually trigger the picture action using the `takePicture` method. So this should address `#2`.

You can use other properties to adjust your image picker too. For example, you can limit the user to only taking images using the `mediaTypes` property.

Comment: Dude !!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444107/help-with-modal-view-controller-login

Comment: Would it be possible to, using Storyboard and an own toolbar, setting the camera to open in a view area? I need a tool bar with some additional buttons.

Comment: Make sure you also get the users permission to access the camera and check if the camera is available `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]`. Also a useful Link: http://hubpages.com/technology/How-to-access-Photo-Camera-and-Library-in-iPhone-Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the docs, `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is deprecated from iOS6 onwards.  Use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` instead.