# Help with Modal View Controller & Login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, loginview

I need some help with modal view controllers, as I have not used Modal View Controllers before...

So this is how my application now is...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[_window addSubview:rootController.view];
rootController.selectedIndex =2;
 NSLog(@"Displaying the APP delegate");
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

}
```

I have a view for Login, titled `LoginViewController` . I want this to appear first as the first view, and on clicking the `Login button (IBAction)`, I want it to show     `rootController.selectedIndex =2;`

(Please ignore the login check as of now). I just want the login view controller to appear at first, and dismiss itself if I press Login, and then take the screen to my rootController (which is a `UITabBarController`)

Comment: Do you want to show a login view at the start, and when dismissed a tab bar controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the viewDidLoad method of the first view in the tabBar present the modal view as follows :

```
LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];

[lvc release];
```

To dismiss the modalView, in the IBAction of the login button just put in the following code :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: So when I dismiss, the view shifts to `[_window addSubview:rootController.view]`;
`rootController.selectedIndex =2;` ?

Comment: You have to put the code in the viewDidLoad of the view loading at index 2. So you will be presenting the modal view from that view. Upon dismissing a modal view, it will go back to view it was presented from which in this case is the index 2 view.

Comment: Think of the modal view as just covering up whatever view is onscreen. When it is dismissed, whatever view was there to begin with will still be there. The point of the modal view is to block user interaction on the main view until the modal view is dealt with.

Comment: Login View Controller appears... but `IBAction` does not seem to dismiss... I write it in the `IBAction of Login View controller`. So using `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`  does not seem to work. Should I reference somthing ?

Comment: Hmmm it should work. Are you doing something else besides dismissing the modal view? Post the code of the IBAction method.

Comment: `-(IBAction) clickLogin: (UIBarButtonItem*) sender{
        
        if (sender == self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem)
        {

    NSLog(@"I clicked login");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
}
}`

Comment: Remove the if condition and then try.

Comment: You need to send the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` message to the same object that you sent the `presentModalViewController:animated:` message. If that `clickLogin:` method is defined in `LoginViewController`, you cannot send the dismiss message to `self`. Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) for more info.

Comment: @Jiri Apple says the preferred approach is to use the parent view controller for dismissing the modal view. It doesn't say that making modal view dismiss by itself is wrong. You can send the dismiss message to self. I have used it many times.

Comment: @HG's yes, you are right, I did not read the documentation I am referring to carefully enough. Thanks.