# Get access to default photo album

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get access to default photo album in iPhone. In [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135) example I got access only to albums created by myself. Is there way to get to default album?

Comment: what do you mean default album?

Comment: @Superman "Camera Roll" album

Comment: that's easy. there are alot of example in the google,mhen.

Comment: I think is the Answer you are looking [Camera Integration][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389375/iphone-xcode-camera-integration-tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this, I have use it, and tweak it a little bit by myself, that it can sustain 1000+ photos that doesnt crash. Here is the project : [AGImagePickerController](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController). Hope you try this :)

Answer (score 1):

Use  **AVAssetLibrary**  fir your requirement.

Refer [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) sample code for getting access to default photo album