# How to launch the default camera app in my app for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I am a cutup for mobile app development.
I have already run the some apps such as safari, sms, ibooks and etc in my app using URL Scheme.
It is very easy, but I couldn't run the default CAMERA app.
Please help me! I think it is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Althought this question will help you understand the thing even better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389375/iphone-xcode-camera-integration-tutorials?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the Camera application, But you can open the camera or gallery from your application.
Please refer to this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/) for a tutorial on `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: Right. Of course I know about it. But I wanna launch the camera app.                    Anyway thanks for this answer!    :)